# Does JavaScript's way of checking type by string comparison affects performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, typechecking

Most of JavaScript's type checking is done by string comparison. For example,

```
if (typeof(x)=='undefined')
```

is the only way of checking if a variable was never defined. Does this have consequences on performance?

Comment: Does it count if x is defined to undefined e.g. `x = undefined;`

Comment: why not use `x === undefined` and ignore the `typeof` all the way?

Comment: @Krycke: If `x` was never defined, you'd get a reference error instead when trying to access it.

Comment: Don't worry about micro-super-tiny-mini-performance issues. This is how you check types in JavaScript so even if it performs poorly (it doesn't), it doesn't matter.

Comment: Keep in mind that string comparison only takes time proportional to the number of leading equal characters. So if "int" is compared to "undefined" it stops after the first character.

Answer (score 0):

That's the only correct way to check for an undefined.
Performance hit for the check is minimal. Here is a simple test you can run and see the actual numbers.

```
function performanceTest(fn, count){
    var start = new Date();
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
        fn.call(fn); 
    }
    var end = new Date();
    console.log(end - start);   
}    

performanceTest(function(){
    typeof fff == 'undefined'
}, 100000);
```

It took 87ms to run the check 100,000 times on chrome.